# SSH Command Line Error on fresh install of Magento 2.2.5 on Bitnami

Tags: command-line, setup-upgrade, ssh, magento-2.2.5, bin-magento

I have tried numerous installations of magento on Bitnami and I keep getting the below error when trying to upgrade using 'sudo php /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento-cli  setup:upgrade':

> Check the user before running the command if [ `id | sed -e s/uid=//g
>   -e s/\(.*//g` -ne 0 ]; then
>       echo "Please run this script using admin privileges (as root user or using sudo). This way, it will  use the proper user to run the
>   Magento's command" >> /dev/stderr
>       exit 1 fi Run the Magento's commands using the web servers' user and group su daemon -s /bin/bash -c "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin/magento $*"

I have tried changing permissions and group users on all files but it doesnt seem to make any difference. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute the `magento-cli` script directly, not via the PHP interpreter:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs
sudo bin/magento-cli setup:upgrade
```

Also, make sure you are logging in to the box as the "bitnami" user.  If you're on EC2, it will by default suggest the "ubuntu" user.  While logging in does work, it appears to cause some issues when the `magento-cli` script attempts to `su daemon`.